# React-Redux Connect StateToProps Using Component Properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm working on learning react and redux more, and so I copied and am modifying this calculator repo to use redux calls: https://github.com/ahfarmer/calculator

I'm having issues when it comes to button presses, however. In the original code, each React Button construct is given a name property when created in the ButtonPanel contstruct. Some buttons also have the field "wide" and "orange" added in the original code, and I'd like to support that functionality still.

For initial changes, I am implementing this with every button sharing a singular click handler just like the original code, although I plan on changing that later.

Here is what I have so far, but every button property seems to be null:

Button.js:

```js
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import "./Button.css";

const Button = (handleClick, orange, wide, name) => {
    const className = [
        "component-button",
        orange ? "orange" : "",
        wide ? "wide" : "",
    ];

    return (
        <div className={className.join(" ").trim()}>
            <button onClick={() => handleClick(name)}>{name}</button>
        </div>
    );
}


Button.propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string,
    orange: PropTypes.bool,
    wide: PropTypes.bool,
    clickHandler: PropTypes.func
};

export default Button
```

ConnectedButton.js

```js
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import calculateValue from "../../store/actions/calculate";
import Button from "./Button";

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
    orange: props.orange,
    wide: props.wide,
    name: props.name,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    handleClick: (nextValue) => (dispatch(calculateValue(nextValue))),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Button);
```

ButtonPanel.js:

```js
import ConnectedButton from "../button/ConnectedButton";
import React from "react";

import "./ButtonPanel.css";

const ButtonPanel = () => (
    <div className="component-button-panel">
        <div>
            <ConnectedButton name="AC" />
            <ConnectedButton name="+/-" />
            <ConnectedButton name="%" />
            <ConnectedButton name="÷" orange />
        </div>
        <div>
            <ConnectedButton name="7" />
            <ConnectedButton name="8" />
            <ConnectedButton name="9" />
            <ConnectedButton name="x" orange />
        </div>
        <div>
            <ConnectedButton name="4" />
            <ConnectedButton name="5" />
            <ConnectedButton name="6" />
            <ConnectedButton name="-" orange/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <ConnectedButton name="1" />
            <ConnectedButton name="2" />
            <ConnectedButton name="3" />
            <ConnectedButton name="+" orange/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <ConnectedButton name="0" wide />
            <ConnectedButton name="." />
            <ConnectedButton name="=" orange />
        </div>
    </div>
);

ButtonPanel.propTypes = {};

export default ButtonPanel;
```

Right now the buttons don't show any text, so fixing that would be the first step and should make it easier to test the click handler. I have a feeling that I am implementing the second argument to mapStateToProps incorrectly possibly, but not sure how

Comment: Your Button component should look like `Button = ({ handleClick, orange, wide, name }) => {}`, Note the braces. This is because a functional component receives a props param, not each prop as an individual param, i.e. `Button = (props) => {}` and using destructuring you get `Button = ({ propA, propB, ...rest }) => {}` so that you can get direct access to the props you need.

Comment: Please be aware that you are learning a very (since 2019) outdated style of Redux here - modern Redux does not use `connect`, switch...case reducers, action type constants, hand written action creators etc. and is about 1/4 of the code as a consequence (and much less suspectible to bugs). You are probably following outdated tutorials. Please follow the [official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) instead.

Comment: In `mapStateToProps` you are overriding name prop with `null` state.name. But as a comment above, this form of redux is outdated, check out the docs.